# Liferay Asset Publisher ADT get Image URL

Tags: liferay, adt

I have created a structure in Liferay 7.2 that has an image selector. When I add the following to the ADT to get the image

```
<#assign
    artImg = saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='Imagean48']")
/>
```

it doesn't return the URL but instead returns a list.

```
<img src=" {" classpk":1923313,"groupid":"1912582","name":"spc_desktop_welcome_image3_benefits.jpg","alt":"man="" in="" suit","title":"spc_desktop_welcome_image3_benefits.jpg","type":"document","uuid":"db10a245-881c-d09c-ab64-4aeebc1581f0","fileentryid":"1923313","resourceprimkey":"2474428"}="" "="">
```

Is it possible to get just the URL of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate `artImg` to a hash

```html
<#assign
  artImg = saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='Imagean48']")
  artImgHash = artImg?eval
/>
```

Get `artImg` DLFileEntry and then its **URL**

```
<#assign
  dlFileEntryLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.document.library.kernel.service.DLFileEntryLocalService")
  dlURLHelper = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.document.library.util.DLURLHelper")

  artImgDLFile = dlFileEntryLocalService.getFileEntryByUuidAndGroupId(artImgHash.uuid, artImgHash.grouId)
  artImgURL = dlURLHelper.getImagePreviewURL(artImgDLFile, themeDisplay)
/>
```

Then you can just use it in your `img`

```html
<img src="${artImgURL}"/>
```

**Note**: I've replicated your `artImg = saxReaderUtil.createXPath...` line but I don't think it works. The right way would be something like this:

```
<#assign 
  journal = entry.getAssetRenderer().getArticle()
  rootElement = saxReaderUtil.read(journal.content).getRootElement()
  artImg = rootElement.selectSingleNode("dynamic-element[@name='Imagean48']")
/>
```